# jQuery infinite slideUp and slideDown without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a title that is in the h3 tag. My code works using slideUp but slideDown looks so bad. I want the slideDown animations smooth like in slideUp. Basically, slideDown from the last array to the first array, and then the cycle continues (an infinite). Here is my code: HTML:

```
<div class="services-slide-up">
    <h3 class="services-it-consulting">IT Consulting</h3>
    <h3 class="services-web-dev">Web Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-mobile-app-dev">Mobile App Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-ui-ux-design">UI/UX Design</h3>
    <h3 class="services-team-dev">Team Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-software-testing">Software Testing</h3>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = [$(".services-it-consulting"), $(".services-web-dev"), $(".services-mobile-app-dev"), $(".services-ui-ux-design"), $(".services-team-dev"), $(".services-software-testing")]; 
  var i = 0;
  function animateDivs() {
    divs[i].slideDown(1000, function() {
      divs[i].slideUp(1000, function() {
        i++;
        if (i >= divs.length) {
          i = 0;
        }
        animateDivs();
      });
    });
  }
  animateDivs();
});
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML code so we can see the issue. Hard to guess what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please also try to explain what you try to achieve, because this looks... amm... there are lots of room for improvement

Answer (score 0):

You have semantic issues and I find the nested slide up / down event very confusing. What you can do is to place a setTimeout on each event and multiply it by a counter. This counter should be consistent also for the slideDown event. A solution could look like the following.

However be aware of memory allocation issues since the setTimeout is executed immediately. So this will create 8 timeout functions in total. Not a big deal at this point but can become an issue, so please be aware of that.

```js
let divs = [$(".services-it-consulting"), $(".services-web-dev"), $(".services-mobile-app-dev"), $(".services-ui-ux-design"), $(".services-team-dev")];
let counter = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){ divs[i].slideUp('slow') }, 1000 * counter);
  counter++;
}

for(let j = divs.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
  setTimeout(function(){ divs[j].slideDown('slow') }, 1000 * counter);
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-slide-up">
    <h3 class="services-it-consulting">IT Consulting</h3>
    <h3 class="services-web-dev">Web Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-mobile-app-dev">Mobile App Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-ui-ux-design">UI/UX Design</h3>
    <h3 class="services-team-dev">Team Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-software-testing">Software Testing</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost. I don't know why it stops the loop on the "Web Development" tag during slideDown.

Comment: Sorry wrong condition in the for loop, test again @JohnMark

Comment: like this, it slides up and down however, the loop ended after the slide down when it reaches the first array, it should start to loop again continous. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
loop();
function loop()
{
    let divs = [$(".services-it-consulting"), $(".services-web-dev"), $(".services-mobile-app-dev"),      $(".services-ui-ux-design"), $(".services-team-dev")];
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function(){ divs[i].slideUp('slow') }, 1000 * counter);
      counter++;
      
    }
    
    var down=1;
    for(let j = divs.length-1; j > 0; j--) {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        divs[j].slideDown('slow');
        down++;
        // base case
        if (down == divs.length) {
            loop();
        }
      }, 1000 * counter);
      counter++; 
    }
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services-slide-up">
    <h3 class="services-it-consulting">IT Consulting</h3>
    <h3 class="services-web-dev">Web Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-mobile-app-dev">Mobile App Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-ui-ux-design">UI/UX Design</h3>
    <h3 class="services-team-dev">Team Development</h3>
    <h3 class="services-software-testing">Software Testing</h3>
</div>
```

I have used to setTimeout to slide up and slide own to call function in looping.see in the code

Comment: Almost. Just like this but the slideDown stops on "Web Development" title it should stop on the first array which is "IT Consulting" and start looping which you did. Thanks